# Ubuntu installation went wrong

Tags: boot, partitioning

So I was following this  official tutorial:

[Make a Live ISO Image of Ubuntu on USB for MacOS](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0)

Then after finishing the making process I boot my Mac from a flash drive and chose the option to Install Ubuntu.

Then I connected a 500gb external hard drive which had a 300gb Time machine backup partition 100Gb file storage partition and a 100gb partition named as "LINUX" for the linux installation. I chose the 100Gb portion as ext4 /.

Then I chose my external hardrive EFI partition for installing the bootloaders.

Then after the installation was complete I restarted my Mac ( Hardrive still connected) and it was stuck on something like "Drive caching" not sure.

Then I force restart my Mac by holding the power button for like 5 seconds and it booted  back with a grub menu. I didn't know what a grub menu meant so I got scared.

I again got scared and force shutdown my MacBook plugged the external hardrive out and started my Mac and saw the grub menu.

I got  really scared that Ubuntu 16.04 could have written something into my Mac's EFI partition. I again force restarted my Mac and hit the option key and chose my Macintosh HD and it booted up fine. Now what really worries me is

1. Maybe a portion of my Mac's firmware could have overwritten
2. May cause problems in the future.

PS. What is GRUB Menu and boot loaders? And why did I see that GRUB Menu?

Thanks!

Comment: **Don't quote me on this**, but I *think* that whenever you install in EFI mode, GRUB is installed to the primary disk's EFI partition regardless of the bootloader setting.

Comment: @AndroidDev But I chose my external hard disk as the installation destination then why would it install on my Mac's internal disk. And I don't see the grub screen anymore. So I think MacOS removed grub itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GRUB` = Grand Unified Bootloader

The beauty of Grub is that it can boot many different environments. To select said environment you **select** the bootloader you wish to boot.

The confusion is GRUB is a *bootloader* and a *booter*

If you are dual booting, you select the partition you want to boot. Thus the bootloader `grub` will dive inside the partition and run the `init` scripts to start the machine. Each OS has their particulars. `grub` worked as intended it sounds like by looking at the efi partition and letting you select from there.

I had a bunch of trouble with messing with EFI and MBR booting methods. However, once you get your head around it, it is not so bad.

Check out Rod Smith's article [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html)

There are more solutions to booting other than `grub` check out [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)